# check execCommand createlink status

Tags: javascript

When making a simple WYSIWYG editor with JavaScript for a textarea I can check the current status of a button (Bold, Italic, Underlined etc) like that:

```
document.queryCommandState("bold")
```

But if I'd like to see if selected text has a link attached, how could I do that (or is it a longer process?). The same query (or queryCommandValue) with "CreateLink" does not seem work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `document.queryCommandState("CreateLink")` (see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536982%28VS.85%29.aspx)) doesn't seem to work, you'll have to get the selection and the [DOM element for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335252/how-can-i-get-the-dom-element-which-contains-the-current-selection/1335347#1335347). If that DOM element is an `a` element, you have the link. If you allow to style the text of a link, you must look further up in the element tree.

Comment: As I said before, that does not work. It just gives me an Exception error "Component returned failure code..".