# How can force copy selected text ? [iPhone]

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, copy-paste, uipasteboard

Hi~ I have one question. ^^

How can i get "selected text" on UIWebView (or UITextView) ?

I'd like to copy "selected text" without copy/paste popup-view.

1) i removed ... copy/paste view. ( it was success~ )

```
UIMenuController *theMenu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
[theMenu setMenuVisible:NO];
[theMenu update];
```

***2. forced copy "selected text" (fail)***

copyController.h -------------------------

```
@interface copyController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
{
     UIWebView *WebView;
}
```

copyController.m ------------------------

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{



    // ----------> here !!!!!
    // I'd like to forced copy "selected text" without copy/paste popup-view

   // ** How can i get selected text ???**


     return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}



- (void)copy:(id)sender
{
     UIPasteboard *board = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
     NSLog(@"SENDER : copied : %@",board.string);
}
```

How can i copy text in canPerformAction. ?

The reason I want to copy "selected text" is just for decorating text by changing color and font.

thx you~

Answer (score 2):

To put string into the pasteboard, use

```
[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string = @"some text";
```

To get selected text from the WebView, use `-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` with [appropriate Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335252/how-can-i-get-the-dom-element-which-contains-the-current-selection).

Comment: You are "my God" ^0^.
I see briliant light in your answer. i will checking now~~~


Thank you so so so very much. (i have suffer from this problem while 5 days)

ps. 
please pardon me my poor english. (i'm korean)