# How to detect when a child-element of a contenteditable DIV is edited via keyboard?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

Given this HTML code:

```
<div contenteditable>
    ....
    <span> child-element </span>
    ....
</div>
```

When the user clicks on the SPAN element (in order to place the caret inside it), and then presses a character key on the keyboard (in order to edit the text-content of the SPAN element), a `keydown`, `keypress`, and `keyup` event will be fired.

However, the `target` property of those corresponding event objects is **not** the SPAN element, but the DIV element itself.

**Live demo:** (Also [on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UKcMa/))

```js
$('div').keydown(function(e) {
    alert( e.target.nodeName );
});
```

```css
div { border:2px solid red; padding:10px; margin:10px; }
span { background-color:yellow; }
```

```html
<div contenteditable>
    BEFORE
    <span>SPAN</span>
    AFTER
</div>

<p>
    Click on the yellow SPAN element (to place the caret inside it), and then press a character key (to change the text-content of the SPAN element). The alert-box shows that the event-target is the DIV element, not the SPAN element...
</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How can I determine whether or not the key-event occurred inside a SPAN element?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This can be done using the selection APIs:

```
$('div').keydown(function(e) {
    if (document.selection) {
        alert(document.selection.createRange().parentElement().tagName); // IE
    } else {
        // everyone else
        alert(window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.tagName); 
    }
});
```

**Note:** The above example is simplistic. See the SO post linked below for a complete solution to the selection problem.

Demo (also [on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/suVdX/)):

```js
$('div').keydown(function(e) {
    if (document.selection)
        alert(document.selection.createRange().parentElement().tagName); // IE
    else
        alert(window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.tagName); // everyone else
});
```

```css
div { border:2px solid red; padding:10px; margin:10px; }
span { background-color:yellow; }
```

```html
<div contenteditable>
    BEFORE
    <span>SPAN</span>
    AFTER
</div>

<p>
    Click on the yellow SPAN element (to place the caret inside it), and then press a character key (to change the text-content of the SPAN element). The alert-box shows that the event-target is the DIV element, not the SPAN element...
</p>
<div id="stuff"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection/anchorNode
- [How can I get the DOM element which contains the current selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335252/how-can-i-get-the-dom-element-which-contains-the-current-selection)

Comment: @Šime - Updated with an IE solution. I found the linked post while researching this. There are more complete answers there.

Comment: One point: `anchorNode` isn't guaranteed to be a text node in all browsers and all situations. Best to check its node type to see if it's an element to be on the safe side.

Comment: @Tim - Yes, definitely. Anyone using my answer really needs to read the other linked SO question, which gets into the specifics. The only reason I'd say this isn't a dupe is because it's in the context of `contenteditable` specifically.

Comment: @Tim - By the way, glad you reinforced this. Most range code I've seen in the wild assumes that start and end nodes are always text nodes, even though the spec clearly states that they aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Making the whole `div` editable means that `<span>` tag is nothing but text content. If you just want the `span` to be editable, set `contentEditable` on the span itself.

Comment: I need the whole DIV to be editable. I use the SPAN elements to give certain words specific styling and behavior...

Comment: This is incorrect. The child elements are still there, and can still be accessed and manipulated. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/o90Lm8jr/