# How can I get the element key pressed in

Tags: javascript, html

If I add an event Listener on click I get the actual element clicked on, whether it's the element I added the listener to or a child element.

But if I do the same for `input`, `keyup`, `keydown`, or `keypress` on a content-editable element, I only get the element the event listener is added on, not child elements, even if the input happened in the child element.

How can I also get the child element when the key is pressed on it?

For instance: Click the word "Child" in the content-editable div below and type, and you'll see that `e.target` is the `div`, not the `span`:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].addEventListener("click",function(e){
  document.getElementsByTagName("b")[0].innerHTML = e.target;
});
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[1].addEventListener("input",function(e){
  document.getElementsByTagName("b")[0].innerHTML = e.target;
});
```

```html
Click:
<div>Parent
  <span>Child</span>
</div>
<br>
Input:
<div contenteditable>Parent
  <span>Child</span>
</div>
<br>

<div>Target:<b></b></div>
```

Comment: This is very interesting. `document.activeElement` is also the div, even when you're typing in the `span`.

Comment: I was about to check getting the active selection when Mina found the duplicate -- which solves this with selection APIs. :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752708/how-to-detect-when-a-child-element-of-a-contenteditable-div-is-edited-via-keyboa

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Can't be more clear in the dupe, so deleted my answer :)