# How to remove backcolor of window.find Highlights

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How to roll back highlights which are caused with the below code

```
if (window.find && window.getSelection) {
     var sel = window.getSelection(); 
     sel.collapse(document.body, 0);  
     document.body.offsetHeight;
     if (window.find(text, true)) { 
        document.execCommand("hiliteColor", false, "YellowGreen"); 
        sel.collapseToEnd(); 
     }
}
```

How to remove all highlights backcolor, i.e "YellowGreen". I have seen a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076341/remove-highlight-added-to-selected-text-using-javascript) that is related to my question. But the accepted answer is not working. Please somebody look into it and help me.

Comment: Are you targeting a specific browser? Firefox perhaps?

Comment: @Hemlock I am targeting only Chrome.

Comment: @Tim Down Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative for this....

```
$('body *').each(function () {
  ($(this).css('background-color') == "rgb(70, 130, 180)") || ($(this).css('background-color') == "rgb(255, 192, 203)") ? $(this).css("background-color", "") : 0;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution. There isn't really enough detail in your question to be able to write something that can drop in, so you'll probably have to tweak it to get what you want.

The idea is to monitor the `DOMNodeInserted` mutation event while the highlight code is running and mark the nodes being inserted with a `className` that can then be used to find and remove them. *Caveat*: mutation events are deprecated, but there really isn't a replacement so I'm using what I have.

```
Highlighter = (function() {
    var highlighting = false;
    document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
        if (highlighting) {
            var target = e.target;
            if (target.nodeType == 1) {
                target.className = CLASS_NAME;
            }
        }
    }, false);

    var CLASS_NAME = 'highlighted';
    return {
        highlight: function(text, color) {
            highlighting = true;            
            var sel = window.getSelection(); 
            sel.collapse(document.body, 0);

            if (window.find(text, true)) { 
                document.execCommand("hiliteColor", false, color); 
                sel.collapseToEnd(); 
            } 
            highlighting = false;
        },

        unhighlight: function() {
            var highlighted = document.querySelectorAll('.' + CLASS_NAME);
            var i = highlighted.length;
            while (i--) {
                var node = highlighted[i];
                node.parentNode.replaceChild(node.firstChild, node);
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

​Tested only in Chrome 17. Here is a fiddle of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/LPJqW/