# Highlight including different nodes

Tags: javascript, html

**EDIT:** I found a good solution in this post [Remove highlight added to selected text using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076341/remove-highlight-added-to-selected-text-using-javascript?rq=1)

I´m making a script to highlight texts. I´m using `<span>` tags. This part was easy but now I come across a problem. When highlighting includes different nodes I need to close the `<span>` tag before the parent close, and open again de `<span>` in the new node. Is not a very good explanation so I put an example:

```
    <body>

       <p id="0">Lorem ipsum</p>

       <div id="1">dolor sit amet</div>

    </body>
```

I select for highlighting :

```
ipsum</p><div id="1">dolor sit
```

Then I have to close `<span>` before `</p>` and open after `<div>` programatically. Any ideas how can I do it? I prefer to do all the script with pure JavaScript, but any help will be appreciated.

Here its my function to highlight:

```
function surroundSelection(element) {



            if (window.getSelection)
            {
                var sel = window.getSelection();
                if (sel.rangeCount)
                {
                    console.log (sel);

                    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();



                    range.surroundContents(element);
                    sel.removeAllRanges();
                    sel.addRange(range);



                }
            }
        }
```

Where element will be the tag ( in my case `<span>`)

Here it is what I have, with still the problem of highlight different nodes 
http://jsfiddle.net/nacles/4L6d57bs/

Comment: Will show any kind of preview or example what you want...

Answer (score 0):

You have to start a different `spam` on every part of the code you, in your example:

```
<span>ipsum</span></p><div id="1"><span>dolor sit</span>
```

so for you, just put a `span` in the begining and then look for the end of the string or a '<' if the tag is opening like

then note that there is a nested tag block, if the tag is a close like

then you just put a closing span.

There are a lot of cases but i think is not very difficult.