# Get parent element of caret in iframe design mode

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, rich-text-editor, designmode

I want to know what is the parent element of caret in an `iframe` with `designMode = 'on'`.
The reason is that want to know if currently user is typing in a `p` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function to do this, adapted from [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1336922/96100):

```
function getSelectionBoundaryElement(win, isStart) {
    var range, sel, container = null;
    var doc = win.document;

    if (doc.selection) {
        // IE branch
        range = doc.selection.createRange();
        range.collapse(isStart);
        return range.parentElement();
    } else if (win.getSelection) {
        // Other browsers
        sel = win.getSelection();

        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            container = range[isStart ? "startContainer" : "endContainer"];

            // Check if the container is a text node and return its parent if so
            if (container.nodeType === 3) {
                container = container.parentNode;
            }
        }
    }
    return container;
}
```

Example use:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("your_iframe_id");
var caretElement = getSelectionBoundaryElement(iframe.contentWindow, true);
```

Comment: I didn't understand what is `isStart` for ?

Comment: @Omid: The function also handles the general case of getting the element containing a selection boundary. `isStart` indicates whether to work with the selection start or end boundary. In the case of a collapsed selection (i.e. just a caret), these are the same, so the value of `isStart` does not matter.