# jQuery can't catch keyup target element in designmode

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

I'm trying to write my own WYSIWYG Editor with jQuery!

I need to catch events which fired on the editor's frame. The `"click"` event is working fine and has the right current element, but `"keyup"` returns only `<body>` as current tag in any place! What did I do wrong?

```
<iframe id="editor"></iframe>
<script>

  // Define editor
  var editor = $('#editor').contents().find('body');

  // Switch to design mode
  $('#editor').contents().prop('designMode', 'on');

  editor.on("click", function(event) {
    console.log("clicked:" + event.target.nodeName + $(this).prop("tagName") + $(event.target).prop("tagName"));
  });

  editor.on("keyup", function(event) {
    console.log("key:" + event.target.nodeName + $(this).prop("tagName") + $(event.target).prop("tagName"));
  });

</script>
```

There is example: [jsfiddle.net/p38L10zp/1](http://jsfiddle.net/p38L10zp/1)

Comment: Are you sure your click event is operating correctly?  For me (latest Chrome for Mac OS X 10.11.2) it displays `clicked:BODYBODYBODY` for the click event output.  I think you need a new approach.  Is the issue that you need multiple frames on a page and you're trying to figure out which on was changed?

Comment: What have you expected to get as the context `this` on `'keyup'`?

Comment: "keyup" it's a keyboard event. For mouse you have to use "mouseup"

Comment: There is example: https://jsfiddle.net/p38L10zp/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options for retrieving the element, which is currently being edited.

1. Use [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) API to determine targeted HTML Element.
2. Use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to track DOM mutations inside the `<iframe>`

### Selection

Please consider a working example of the first approach in this **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5m8dc6g5/)**.

The example is heavily inspired by another SO question [Get parent element of caret in iframe design mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546568/get-parent-element-of-caret-in-iframe-design-mode).

### MutationObserver

The use of this API might be somewhat tricky, [here's](https://jsfiddle.net/no8cr3dv/) a working example for a  very specific use-case.

And the code:

```
var editor = $('#editor').contents().find('body');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation);

    if (mutation.type === 'characterData') {
        console.log('Tag name is: ' + mutation.target.parentNode.tagName);
    }
  });
});

// Configuration of the observer.
var config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  characterData: true,
  subtree: true
};

observer.observe(editor[0], config);

$('#editor').contents().prop('designMode', 'on');

editor.append("<p>Test <b>bold</b> text</p>");
```