# Get id of child div within contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, contenteditable, jquery-events

```
<div class="pad" id="test" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
       <div id="a0" class="fif" > text0</div>
       <div id="a1" class="fif" >text1</div>
       <div id="a2" class="fif" >text2</div>
     </div>
```

As in above code there is a **contenteditable div** with some child divs inside it. I need a jQuery to return the **id** of the child div over which I am **typing**. e.g. if I am editing **text1** it should give me (return) **"a1"**.

It works as desired if I use

```
var clicked;
$('#test').click(function(event){
   clicked = $(event.target);
   alert(clicked.attr('id'));
});`
```

as shown here

http://jsfiddle.net/bernie1227/cK69Q/ **(i.e. on clicking it returns id="a1")** but it doesn't work in similar manner if I use

```
var clicked;
$('#test').keypress(function(event){
   clicked = $(event.target);
   alert(clicked.attr('id'));
});
```

as shown here http://jsfiddle.net/hari_OM/bLgkv/ **i.e. on typing it returns "id=test" and  not "id=a1"**

I tried using `event.target.id` and  `$(this).attr("id")` but they return **id="test"** and not **id="a1"** , but I need to get **"a1"**. I also tried injecting `onkeypress="funcname(this.id)"`  within child divs and retriving it from defined function, but it **doesn't work**.

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1336922/96100

Comment: Yo! Got it working with Tim's link http://jsfiddle.net/MeetM/fmums/#base

Answer (score 0):

I have written a solution which relies on tracking the target of the event, using `event.target`:
http://jsfiddle.net/bernie1227/cK69Q/

Comment: That is not what I want.It works well for **$('#test').click(function(event){..**  but it does not work for **$('#test').keypress(function(event){..** as I have shown it here [  http://jsfiddle.net/hari_OM/bLgkv/](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_OM/bLgkv/) . In case of keypress it shows **id=test** and not **id=a1**.

Answer (score 0):

Ever looked into this? DOMCharacterDataModified

```
$(document).on('DOMCharacterDataModified',  function( event ) {
    if($(event.target).parent().attr('id') === 'parentid') {
        console.log(
            'target',$(event.target),"\r"
        );  
    }
});
```