# create URL with anchor to text selection

Tags: javascript, html, text, anchor, selection

I would like to create a URL pointing to a web service I write, `http://mycoolthing.com`, together with an #-anchor that refers to a *text selection* on that page.

Is is possible in HTML/JS to create an anchor that refers to a Selection or a RangeObject?

Comment: No quite sure what you mean by text selection. Do you mean a word or sentence in the middle of a bigger chuck of text?

Comment: If it's some specific text, you could wrap it in a `span` and assign an id to it, then the browser will scroll the page to the element that has the id specified in the # (although it will not select anything, but you could use a solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse to select the text)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

chromium based browsers now support Scroll To Text Fragment

https://chromestatus.com/feature/4733392803332096#:~:text=This%20feature%20allows%20a%20user,and%20scrolls%20it%20into%20view.

Comment: +1 for Text Fragment URLs for this use case. Google offers a [polyfill](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/text-fragments-polyfill) for browser that don't support this API natively. You can read up more details about this feature in this [article](https://web.dev/text-fragments/).

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in a comment, here is an option to select the text by using JavaScript and the hash (#) on the url.

It is divided in two parts:

1. The calling page will have a link to the target page (they can be the same) with a # indicating the text that you want to select (or if you know it, the ID of the element):

   `<a href="myPage.html#Lorem">Link to my page with Lorem select</a>`
2. The target page will have some JavaScript code that will select the text indicated in the # (if the hash is a valid element id, it will select the text within that element instead of the text).

*Notice that for this solution I used some code from [Selecting text in an element (akin to highlighting with your mouse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse) (Kimtho6's solution)

```
/**
 * SelectText: function from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse (Kimtho6 solution)
 * 
 * element: string that contains an element id (without the #)
 */
function SelectText(element) {
    var doc = document;
    var text = doc.getElementById(element);    
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) { // ms
        var range = doc.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        var range = doc.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(text);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);

    }
}

/**
 * selectHashText: function that selects the first appearance of a text (or an element with the id) indicated in the location hash
 */
function selectHashText() {

    // check if there's an element with that ID
    if ($(document.location.hash).length == 0) {

        // select some text in the page
        var textToSelect = document.location.hash.substring(1);

        // if it's not an empty hash
        if (textToSelect != "") {

            // iterate the different elements in the body
            $("body *").each(function() {

                // if one contains the desired text
                if ($(this).text().indexOf(textToSelect) >= 0) {

                    // wrap the text in a span with a specific ID
                    $(this).html(
                        $(this).html().replace(textToSelect, "<span id='mySelect'>" + textToSelect + "</span>")
                    );

                    // select the text in the specific ID and stop iteration
                    SelectText("mySelect");
                }
            });
        }

    } else {
        // select the content of the id in the page
        SelectText(document.location.hash.substring(1));
    }
}

// execute the text selection on page load and every time the hash changes
$(window).on("hashchange", selectHashText);
$(document).ready(function() { selectHashText(); });
```

I created this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u0x3pst4/), but it doesn't take the # so it doesn't help much. You can also [see it on this web page](http://alvaromontoro.com/tests/hash.html). Notice that is the same code as in the jsfiddle (and above), just on one page.

---

**UPDATE**: (Elaborated from the comments below)

Without using the hash, you can pass the text that you want to select as a parameter in the GET or POST (I will use GET for simplicity):

```
<a href="myPage?select=Lorem">Select Lorem</a>
```

Then using your back-end language (I used PHP, you could use any other or even JavaScript parsing the location href), save the text into the `textToSelect` variable that I used before. As a last step, replace the `.text()` for `.html()` that I used (so the tags are included in the search too)

```
/**
 * gup: function from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter (Haim Evgi's solution)
 * 
 * name: string that contains the name of the parameter to return
 */
function gup( name ) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
    var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
    return results == null ? null : results[1];
}

/**
 * selectHashText: function that selects the first appearance of a text (or an element with the id) indicated in the "select" parameter
 */
function selectTextAcross() {

    // get the "select" parameter from the URL
    var textToSelect = decodeURIComponent(gup("select"));

    // if it's not an empty hash
    if (textToSelect != "") {

        // iterate the different elements in the body
        $("body *").each(function() {

            // if one contains the desired text
            if ($(this).html().indexOf(textToSelect) >= 0) {

                // wrap the text in a span with a specific ID
                $(this).html(
                    $(this).html().replace(textToSelect, "<span id='mySelect'>" + textToSelect + "</span>")
                );

                // select the text in the specific ID and stop iteration
                SelectText("mySelect");
            }
        });
    } 
}

$(document).ready(function() { selectTextAcross(); });
```

---

You can [see it working on this web page](http://alvaromontoro.com/tests/hash2.html?select=Lorem).

About this solution:

- It works (hey! better than nothing! :P)
- You can include html tags (you cannot with the # one)
- You need to know the document's source
- The generated code may not be valid and then the result may not be the expected one (all the browsers I tested with, they stop selecting after the first "crossed" tag)

Comment: Great work, thanks! Do you think it's possible to make the selection unique across the page by not including the literal text in the anchor, but the range/selection object you created above?

Comment: Just trying to make sure that I understand what you want: specifying a range within the ID? like for example if I have `<div id='myId'>This is a test</div>`, and you want to select only "test", you'd pass a range of the type 10,4 (beginning of the text, and size). Is that correct? Something like `#myId&range=10,4`? or just the range?

Comment: Unfortunately I have to assume that the selection is across multiple `div`s, e.g., `abc <div id='myId'>This is a test</div> 123`, and I want the selection of `abc This`. At first I thought the JS `SelectionObject` is what I want until I noticed it contains the the selected text explicitly, making this object generally unsuitable for inclusion into an URL (since URLs can only be 1024 chars long).

Comment: hmmm... I could change the solution so it ignores tags. The problem is that it would work fine for nested tags (`<div>....Text <div>you want</div> to select....</div>`), but it could create problems across tags (`<div>....Text you want</div><div>to select....</div>`). For example, in the code that you mention, the resulting code could include "crossed-nested" (`<div><span></div><div></span></div>`, I don't know the name in English) tags that is invalid HTML and the behavior would depend on the browser interpretation

Comment: I added a solution that allows to go over HTML tags, but notice how it breaks when it goes across HTML tags, generating invalid HTML (probably it can be fixed parsing the document differently)

Answer (score 1):

According to this site, you can use javascript in order to find some text in the page.

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/searchin.htm

Perhaps you can create a link to the site and include the text selection with GET or POST so when the other page is loaded, you can go to the text selection using javascript and the information from the previous page.

Something like this in the first page:

```
window.location.href="url?text=textToFind"
```

And in the other page:

```
$(function () {
window.find(window.location.search)
});
```

Comment: The text I would like to mark might appear several times on the page, so I'm doubtful that an actual search is really what I want here.

Comment: Does the text have any specific feature?
maybe you can combine the search and verify the dom element where is located. According to this question is possible:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335252/how-can-i-get-the-dom-element-which-contains-the-current-selection

Answer (score 0):

Look at 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.execCommand

**createLink**

> Creates an anchor link from the selection, only if there is a selection. This requires the HREF URI string to be passed in as a
>   value argument. The URI must contain at least a single character,
>   which may be a white space. (Internet Explorer will create a link with
>   a null URI value.)

like

```
document.execCommand('createLink', false, 'http://google.com');
```

Comment: Quoting from the site: "When an HTML document has been switched to designMode, [...]". This is not exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected (highlighted) text with

```
var txt = window.getSelection().toString();
```

and then build an anchor using that value

```
href="abc.html#' + txt;
```