# Using a URL to insert data

Tags: html, css, url

I have the following url: `https://www.amazon.com/#twotabsearchtextbox`. When I click on this link I would like it to go to Amazon, select the search bar, and input a value. My question is: how do I modify the URL to insert a value into the search bar?

*Example Input*

**URL:** `https://www.amazon.com/#twotabsearchtextbox`

**Value:** Avengers Movie

*Expected Output:*

[image]

I know you can select elements. I've also seen this done before somewhere. However, I cannot find a resource that explains the identifiers used. I saw you could [highlight it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965819/create-url-with-anchor-to-text-selection) but not insert.

Comment: Why not just dynamically link the search result directly?

Comment: I have a long list of items and I want to save myself the trouble of searching/copy/pasting all the results. Essentially automating the process.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there's something I'm missing, but I'd populate the search link.

`<a href="https://www.amazon.com/s?k=YOUR+SEARCH+VALUE">`

Like previously mentioned, you can even populate the value to whatever you'd like using some javascript. For example:

You have an anchor with an `id` containing what you want to search.

`<a id="star+wars">My Link</a>`

We can use javascript to populate the search URL with your search term, then add it to the anchor using `setAttribute`

```
let yourLink = document.getElementById("star+wars");
let searchID = yourLink.id;

yourLink.setAttribute("href", "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=" + searchID);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L5afroh1/