# How to get the index of a specific text marked by the user (mouse)

Tags: javascript, jquery

The question is sort of self explanatory. I'm trying to get the index of an specific text inside of a div after the user selects it with the mouse, so I can store it on a database. The idea is to retrieve that record from the database and wrap that text in a span tag using the index stored.

Thanks!

Comment: Any code that you have tried?

Comment: Yes, I THINK i'm in the right direction by using window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0); but i'm not sure which of the elements from a Range object can help me to achieve what i'm trying to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335252/how-can-i-get-the-dom-element-which-contains-the-current-selection

Comment: @AmrElGarhy that will give the the DOM element which contains the current selection, but not the index of the text itself