# Get the nodes of selected html using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, getselection

I want to access all the nodes that are in selected area of HTML.

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
```

How to proceed after that?

Comment: I was curious how you could have such a high reputation score with such a poor question, then noticed that you ask lots of questions then answer them as well. Makes me remember what is wrong with this site!

Comment: I am from different domain, for some work, I have to work with Javascript for Android WebView.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
sel.toString()
```

To get the content of the selection

Check this other post that uses the onMousUp event to see on what element the selection ends:
[How can I get the DOM element which contains the current selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335252/how-can-i-get-the-dom-element-which-contains-the-current-selection)

```
function getSelectionBoundaryElement(isStart) {
    var range, sel, container;
    if (document.selection) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.collapse(isStart);
        return range.parentElement();
    } else {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt) {
            if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
                range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            }
        } else {
            // Old WebKit
            range = document.createRange();
            range.setStart(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);
            range.setEnd(sel.focusNode, sel.focusOffset);

            // Handle the case when the selection was selected backwards (from the end to the start in the document)
            if (range.collapsed !== sel.isCollapsed) {
                range.setStart(sel.focusNode, sel.focusOffset);
                range.setEnd(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);
            }
       }

        if (range) {
           container = range[isStart ? "startContainer" : "endContainer"];

           // Check if the container is a text node and return its parent if so
           return container.nodeType === 3 ? container.parentNode : container;
        }   
    }
}
```

See an example at: http://jsfiddle.net/pmrotule/dmjsnghw/

Comment: I do not need the text, i need the html.