# How to create a chrome plugin/extensions with Bubble button (floating property)?

Tags: javascript, json, plugins, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a **chrome extensions**, so that this **plugin** used to send the selected text from a site to a server and return the text back to client.
How can I make my plugin to **float** on the  site, once the user select any text then my plugin must appear beside the selected text (Bubble), exactly like *google translation plugin*, which appears immediately when a user select some text.

I attached some picture to explain what I want exactly!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can read out the current element where you select the text and from there you can put your icon with some distance.

Here you can find out how to get the current element:

[How can I get the DOM element which contains the current selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335252/how-can-i-get-the-dom-element-which-contains-the-current-selection)

With jQuery, you can easily put your icon next to the start of the selection. I have not tried id but this is how I would do that.

Comment: Sorry it is not clear, may be not related to my question