# Finding previous element of a certain class, given a text selection, regardless of DOM structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

As in the attached image, my goal is to select a text, for instance "Among the Helvetii" and find which element among those of class nMarker was before the selection.

[image: Code with paragraphs and markers]

In other words, I’d like to select "Among the Helvetii" and find somehow the element of class nMarker, which has data-marker equal to 1.

Unfortunately I have not a single chance to use jQuery prevAll, prev, closest, etc. as the DOM is unknown, so I can’t count of parents, ancestors, etc. as the marker is placed after a number of words, following an algorithm (it is a requirement I can’t change).

What I achieved so far was to implement this cose, which works if the selection is in the same element where the marker is. But I’d like a solution working without knowing the DOM structure, as I said.

```
var sel = window.getSelection ? window.getSelection() : document.selection.createRange();
if(sel.getRangeAt){ // That’s for Firefox
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    var newNode = document.createElement("span");
    newNode.setAttribute('class', 'justSelected');
    range.surroundContents(newNode);

    $(".justSelected").prevAll(".nMarker").data( "marker")
}
```

Comment: At a stab, to give you something to consider: after checking in the current node, loop `$(this).parents()` nodes, run a `.find(".nMarker").last()` on each of those parent, if found then break otherwise continue

Comment: Is this marker always going to be on the same “ancestor level” as the marked text? What I mean by that, your marked text in the example is in a paragraph, and the marker you are looking for, is inside of a _sibling_ paragraph – or could it be in other, arbitrary locations? Could stuff like `<div><marker/><p>…marked text…</p></div>` or `<div><p><marker/></p></div> <p>…marked text…</p>` also occur?

Comment: @CBroe no, the problem is exactly this one. Markers could be anywhere. Unfortunately I have to deal with non standard ePubs, so they can be wherever, so yes, it can occur what you say. Below I posted a possible answer abandoning the HTML/jQuery approach. But it works only if the selection is unique in the html (chapter) file.

Comment: I guess you should start with something like this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/1335347/1427878, to get the element that the current selection is in. Once you have that, it becomes a matter of DOM traversal (loop through previous siblings, check in there, if no marker found, move up to the next common parent element, repeat the process …)

Comment: What do you mean by *"cose"* in *"implement this cose"*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a non-jQuery approach I managed it like this:

```
var body = $("body").text();
var toFind = window.getSelection().toString();
var strRegEx = '{:(?:(?!{:).)*?'+toFind; 
var res = body.match(strRegEx);
console.log(res);
var regExp = /\{:([^)]+)\:}/;
var matches = regExp.exec(res[0]);
alert(matches[1]);
```

Anyway this doesn't answer completely the question (I wanted to get the data-marker attribute) but now I get the same number.
This works, however, only if the selection is unique in the whole text.