# How to test if selected text is a link?

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

I have a very simple WYSIWYG editor using contenteditable. It works fine, but I want to test if the selected text is being used as a link.  When I use document.queryCommandState('CreateLink'), it always returns false, even if the text is within an anchor.  Example below.

Am I doing this wrong, or is there another way to test if the text is currently used as a link?

```
<script>
    function testLink () {

        // check if this is a link
        var state = document.queryCommandState('CreateLink');
        alert(state);

        // create the link
        document.execCommand ('CreateLink', false, 'http://www.example.com');
    }
</script>

<div contenteditable="true">Here is some sample text to test with.</div>
<br /><br />
<button onclick="testLink();">Test the state of the create link command</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an old thread, but as I am currently working on the same problem, I want to point you to an already existing answer: [check execCommand createlink status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333919/check-execcommand-createlink-status)

In short, the queryCommandState("CreateLink") does not seem to work that way. I use rangy to work with selections in my WYSIWYG Editor. I check, if the parent Node is an anchor and then get the href of the anchor to write it into my link-dialog. Here is a simplified example from my script:

```
var range = rangy.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var container = range.commonAncestorContainer;
if (container.nodeType == 3) {container = container.parentNode;}
if(container.nodeName === "A") {alert ("Yes, it's an anchor!");}
```

Comment: Work like a charm